# Rails controller rendering HTML as plain text, instead of a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

On my site I want a form to be rendered based on what type of data the user is inputing. When I call the controller method in my view, it's outputting tons of HTML where the form should be as plain text starting from DOCTYPE to .  I'm using a post form that was previous in place statically to try it out.

Controller:

```
def feed_form(form_type)

 form_type = %w{type_1 type_2}.include?(form_type) ? form_type : 'post'
 render "_#{form_type}_form"
end
```

And the view calling the action:

```
= feed_form 'post'
```

And the form:

```
  .feed-form
%h3 News Feed
= form_for(@post) do |f|
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object
  .field
    = f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Make your new post here..." 
  = f.submit "Post", class: "post-button"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are don't supposed to call controller methods from a view.

You must prepare all the data for view rendering (e.g. all required models) in controller method, and put it into `@variables`.

And then in view you write all your html using already prepared `@variables`, you can call helpers methods from a view, but not controller's.

Try to put your `def feed_form(form_type)` code into a helper.

*P.S.: and read something about MVC architecture.*

Comment: I forgot to mention I had "helper method: form_feed" in my controller, i thought it would provide the same functionality, but once I moved it into my helper it worked fine.  I will look into helper_method